# Not Able to Run behave command from powershell getting Error "The term 'behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: python, python-behave

I have installed Behave for my BDD Project but not able to execute `behave` command from PowerShell. command line is not accessible at work station

Not able to run the bheave command even though `behave` package is installed, I can run successfully through behave configuration in intellij

When I'm executing behave command from feature directory getting below **error**

```
Projects\python\PythonBehaveBDD\features> behave behave : The term 'behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + behave + ~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (behave:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You've got a typo - it's behave, not "bheave".

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) | [Why do we hate screenshots so much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/)

Comment: (blaze-test-automation-qa-env) PS C:\Arpan Saini\Automation-Projects\python\PythonBehaveBDD\features> behave
behave : The term 'behave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ behave
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (behave:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: even Behave is not reconizable. Sorry i added the incorrect screenshot

Answer (score 1):

1. Set behave.exe file location in path variable
   i found my behave.exe at below location **C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts**
2. Restart your system.

**After than when i run behave command. it was working as expected.**

[image]